# Implementar el patron FACTORY

Tags: arquitectura-de-software

tengo este codigo en el cual creo dos tipos de participantes, el codigo se hace muy largo y creo que puedo aplicar el patron **FACTORY**,  pero no se como implementarlo, debo crear una dos clases especificas "**ParticipanteOWner**" y "**ParticipanteNormal**"?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero crear esas clases basandome en esa imagen de FACTORY PATTERNS, en la cual existe clases especificas **LusuryCar, SmallCar y SedanCar**

```
    public Meet createRelacion(Long idOwner, Long idUser) {
            Meet currentMeet = new Meet();
            Bet bet = new Bet();
            bet.setInversion(100);
            currentMeet.setBet(bet);
            currentMeet.setState(State.start);
            currentMeet.setName(Math.random() + "");

            User user = userRepository.findById(idUser);
            User owner = userRepository.findById(idOwner);

            Bet betParticipant = new Bet();
            betParticipant.setInversion(0);
    ///////////////////   PRIMER PARTICIPANTE/////////////////
            Participant participant = new Participant();    //
            participant.setRol(Rol.NORMAL);            //
            participant.setMeet(currentMeet);               //
            participant.setUser(user);                      //
            participant.setBet(betParticipant);             //
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
            participantRepository.save(participant);
    ///////////////////   SEGUNDO PARTICIPANTE//////////////////
            Participant participantOwner = new Participant();///
            participantOwner.setMeet(currentMeet);           /// 
            participantOwner.setRol(Rol.OWNER);              ///
            participantOwner.setUser(owner);                 ///
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            participantRepository.save(participantOwner);
            return currentMeet;
        }
```

Comment: ¿Cual sería la diferencia entre "ParticipanteOWner" y "ParticipanteNormal?

Comment: @AlvaroC. solo el rol es la diferencia

Comment: ¿no convendría entonces que mejor fuera un atributo en lugar de una clase distinta?

Comment: @AlvaroC. claro que puede ser un atributo, pero creo que debe existir una fabrica que cree participantes